# Sorting: performance evaluation between general sort and key-indexed counting

Tags: c++, sorting, performance-testing

According to [String Sorts: Algorithms Fourth Edition](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/51radix/),

> Key-Indexed Counting is an extremely effective and often overlooked sorting method for applications where keys are small integers.

Here is my implementation of `key-indexed counting`:

```
void kIC(std::vector<int> &a, int R) {
    std::vector<int> aux(a.size());
    auto count = new int[R + 1];
    std::fill_n(count, R + 1, 0);
    for (const auto & v : a)
        count[v + 1]++;
    for (int r = 0; r < R; r++)
        count[r + 1] += count[r];
    for (const auto & v : a)
        aux[count[v]++] = v;
    a = aux;
    delete[] count;
}
```

Then I use 0.1 billion small integers to test the performance between the algorithm and built-in (general) sorting. And the following is how I construct the initial data.

```
    vector<int> data;
    data.reserve(100000000);
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    const int R = 128;
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, R - 1);
    for (int n = 0; n < 100000000; n++)
        data.push_back(dis(gen));
```

However, from my testing, `sort(data.begin(), data.end())` is always better than `kIC(data, R)`, or at least the difference is trivial.

So, what is the advantage of `key-indexed counting`? Could anyone give me a scenario where **key-indexed counting** method outperforms **general sorting**?

Comment: `auto count = new int[R + 1];...delete [] count;` --  You are issuing a call to the allocator here, which affects your timing results.  Refactor the code in some way to remove that call to `new[] / delete[]` each time -- maybe use `std::vector<int> count;` `resize()` it accordingly, and then pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: Also make sure you are timing a release or optimized version of your program, not a "debug" or unoptimized version.

Comment: For arrays with large numbers of duplicate keys，`quick sort` with 3-way partitioning can reach linear-time performance.